# MySQL replication mystery

Tags: mysql, replication

May I ask if its possible to have a table on Slave server. But it does not exist on Master Servers? how come this one happens? Thank you.

Comment: There could be multiple reasons for the same and may be Slave is not read-only and someone have created the table  on slave directly or recent switch/fail over may have caused this

Comment: Is the data being updated on the slave? Are you using native mysql replication or a third-party tool for replication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is currently being updated on the replica, it could be due to a trigger (show triggers from [database];) or a replication rewrite flag (look at the my.cnf for master and slave).

Comment: Why the replication is still running? All I know is when its updated on slave servers the replication might not continue.

Comment: Replication could continue fine even without a matching schema. That is especially true with an extra table on the replica. If no updates come from the master for that table, replication won't break.